# Is there a way to use Point struct in Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

It appears that there is no way to reference System.Windows.Point from within Portable Class Library. Before I implement my own Point structure, I'd like to be sure that this is correct. Do I need to build my own Point class?

Comment: If you look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx) page it will tell you exactly which platforms support which classes / functions (look at the version information section).

Comment: That's correct, just as there is no way to do simple things like draw a line between points.  Highly platform dependent, you'll have to make your own.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to factor out the calculations for the line to be cross platform, while leaving the actual drawing to be implemented for each platform separately. No biggy to implement my own, just wanted to be sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat).  It's got PCL support for PointF, at least (as well as rectangles, colors, images, etc.).

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for. Thanks.